# Semantic UI React Can't resolve './themes/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot'

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, craco

everyone.
I've try to customize semantic-ui in react with craco by follow this instuction, and I try to yarn start but I face this error:

`Error: Can't resolve './themes/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot'`

This is the bottom of my `theme.config`

```
/*******************************
Folders
*******************************/

/* Path to theme packages */
@themesFolder : 'themes';

/* Path to site override folder */
@siteFolder : '../../src/semantic-ui/site';

@import (multiple) "~semantic-ui-less/theme.less";
@fontPath : '../../../themes/@{theme}/assets/fonts';

/*******************************
Import Theme
*******************************/

/@import (multiple) "theme.less";/
@import (multiple) "~semantic-ui-less/theme.less";

/* End Config */
```

How to solve this issue?